# jQuery getting value from dropdown not working

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown like so:

```
<div id="search">
<select id="price-dropdown" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="0">-- Select Price --</option>
                                    <option value="1">$200,000 to $299,999</option><option value="3">$300,000 to $399,999</option><option value="5">$400,000 to $499,999</option><option value="8">$500,000+</option>                               </select>
</div>
```

and I am trying to get the value of the dropdown menu on change:

```
$('#search').change(function() {
alert($('#price-dropdown').val());
});
```

but the alert returns 0....what am I doing wrong?

I have 4 dropdown menus and I am trying to grab all of the values from the dropdown and pass them to a function:

```
$('#search').change(function() {
        var price = $('#price-dropdown').val();
        var type = $('#type-dropdown').val();
        var sqft = $('#sqft-dropdown').val();
        var modelName = $('#model-name-dropdown').val();
        getSearchResults(price, type, sqft, modelName);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#search` is a `div` element which doesn't have a `change` event. You need to hook to the event on the `select` instead. Try this:

```js
$('#price-dropdown').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
    <select id="price-dropdown" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">-- Select Price --</option>
        <option value="1">$200,000 to $299,999</option>
        <option value="3">$300,000 to $399,999</option>
        <option value="5">$400,000 to $499,999</option>
        <option value="8">$500,000+</option>                               
    </select>
</div>
```

---

Given your update you simply need to run the event when any of those `select` elements change. Try this:

```
$('#price-dropdown, #type-dropdown, #sqft-dropdown, #model-name-dropdown').change(function() {
    var price = $('#price-dropdown').val();
    var type = $('#type-dropdown').val();
    var sqft = $('#sqft-dropdown').val();
    var modelName = $('#model-name-dropdown').val();
    getSearchResults(price, type, sqft, modelName);
});
```

Comment: This would work, yes, but my issue is that I have 5 dropdown menus and on change I want to get all of those values of the 5 dropdown menus and pass them to a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#price-dropdown').change(function(){
  alert($(this).val());    
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/f95xp9sn/#base)**